# How can I convert from big.Rat to a string without specifying precision?

Tags: go

I have an endpoint implemented in golang that can receive amounts with different precision length, ie:

```
"123"
"123.12"
"123.123123"
```

I'm using big.Rat internally to deal with these numbers as follows:

```
import (
    "encoding/json"
    "math/big"
)

type MyStruct struct {
    Amount   big.Rat `json:"amount"`
}

func (mystr *MyStruct) MarshalJSON() ([]byte, error) {
    type Alias MyStruct

    return json.Marshal(&struct {
        Amount json.Number `json:"amount"`
        *Alias
    }{
        Amount: json.Number(mystr.Amount.FloatString(2)),
        Alias:  (*Alias)(mystr),
    })
}

func (mystr *MyStruct) UnmarshalJSON(data []byte) error {
    type Alias MyStruct

    aux := &struct {
        Amount json.Number `json:"amount"`
        *Alias
    }{
        Alias: (*Alias)(mystr),
    }

    if err := json.Unmarshal(data, &aux); err != nil {
        return err
    }

    mystr.Amount = mystr.toRat(aux.Amount.String())

    return nil
}

func (mystr *MyStruct) toRat(val string) big.Rat {
    ratAmount := new(big.Rat)
    ratAmount.SetString(val)

    return *ratAmount
}
```

My problem & question is related to the Marshal method, in particular with this line:

`Amount: json.Number(mystr.Amount.FloatString(2)),`

Because if the amount in the json has a number with more than two decimal places a rounding takes place and I don't want that, I just want to mantain exactly the same number that was
received when I did the Unmarshal method.

This is an example of rounding: https://play.golang.org/p/U6oi_aGc8lE

Is there a way to convert from big.Rat to string without defining the precision?

Thank you very much in advance!

Comment: JSON numbers are always float64, so while you can marshal/unmarshal from/to other Go types, the limit of precision of the number in the JSON will always be float64 because that's how numbers are defined in JSON itself.

Comment: So.. what you are saying is that there is no need to use big.Rat in this case, is that what you mean?

Comment: I don't know what your needs are. You might need `big.Rat` internally for whatever work you're doing on the data. You might need to persist `big.Rat`'s precision to JSON, in which case just marshal the `big.Rat` which will marshal to a string rather than a number, since this allows it to maintain arbitrary precision. I don't have enough information on your use case to say what you need to do; what I do know is that JSON itself uses float64 for all number values.

Comment: The only thing I need is to support large amounts of money, that's all I need.


I *don't* even need to perform operations with those numbers just read them and then pass them to another layer as a string without any rounding

Comment: But if you say json is limited by float64 then I don't see the need to use big.Rat

Comment: float64 can represent the gross world product of 2019 with penny precision. It's probably sufficient. But again, what JSON can represent isn't necessarily relevant to what type you want to use internally, depending on your use case.

Comment: Thanks Adrian your comments are really helpful.

I think that in this case it is relevant because the number that I receive in the json it is already limited by float64, so the number is never going to be bigger than a float64

Comment: If you're working with money amounts and doing financial software, you should almost certainly use a decimal floating point representation internally. This usually means using `big.Rat` as you are doing. See also https://github.com/golang/go/issues/19787. There are some third party decimal implementations as well.

Comment: Thanks torek! sadly I cannot change the lib, I must use ``big.Rat``,

Answer (score 1):

This should be help:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "math/big"
    "strconv"
)

func main() {
    n := new(big.Rat)

    n.SetString("34.999999")
    x,_ := n.Float64()
    fmt.Println("Result: "+strconv.FormatFloat(x, 'f', -1, 64))
}
```

Comment: Good answer! but what if the number is too big, what happens when I convert from rat to float a really big number?. Is there a way to do it without using the float type?

Comment: If you convert a large number with a large decimal, the precision round  with defined round mode. To manage this you should be use the decimal package from shopspring.

Comment: But the big.Rat type doesn't have the ``SetMode`` method how can I change that

Comment: Read RoundingMode https://golang.org/pkg/math/big/#RoundingMode

Comment: I read it and it seems that can only be used with the big.Float type not big.Rat

Comment: Yes, my fault. Sorry.